# Fortranform output in double precision

Tags: output-formatting, output, fortran

I want to take the output in fortran form but written in double precision notation.
For example,

```
exp=1 + 8*as^2*Log[2*x]
```

which gives

```
FortranForm[exp]=1 + 8*as**2*Log(2*x)
```

but I want as

```
FortranForm[exp]=1.0D0 + 8.0D0*as**2.0D0*dLog(2.0D0*x)
```

Basically everything is written in double precision.
I can always do replacement in mathematica file, eg.

```
exp /. {Log->dLog} etc.
```

However I was wondering is there any more intrinsic way to have the output format.

Comment: `CForm` and `FortranForm` don't deal with most function names. They're left up to you.  `CForm[Log[x]]` gives `Log(x)` which isn't a standard C function.  A common solution with C is to `#define Log whateverYouWant`.  The other possible solution is the replace you mention.